# Determine abelian groups with 48 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am just doing some revision for my linear algebra exam, and I came across this problem:

> Determine all abelian groups (up to isomorphism) with exactly 48 elements.

I am not sure I have ever seen a similar problem, so I am not sure how to approach it. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with groups, abelian, etc... if yes, are you familiar with sylow theorems?

Comment: $48 = 2^4\times 3$. Use this and See-Woo's hint about the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups. To clarify, for a finite abelian group, the $p_i's$ that show up in the factorization of $G$ are precisely the prime factors of its order.

Answer (score 4):

The most important theorem (maybe) for Abelian groups is [Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group) :

> For any finitely generated abelian group $G$, it is isomorphic to 
>   \begin{align}
> \mathbb{Z}^{r}\times \mathbb{Z}/p_{1}^{e_{1}}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}/p_{r}^{e_{r}}
> \end{align}
>   for some $r, e_{1}, \dots, e_{r}\geq 0$ and prime numbers $p_{1}, \dots, p_{r}$ (can be same).

For a finite group $G$, $r=0$ and $G\simeq \mathbb{Z}/p_{1}^{e_{1}}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}/p_{r}^{e_{r}}$. Now you can classify those groups. For example, there are two order 4 abelian groups : $\mathbb{Z}/4$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2$.